Access error when running Python script via airflow
I installed the airflow docker image according to official documentation, dropped 2 folders from the Ubuntu 22 host into containers, 1 folder with scripts, the second in environments, I launch the dag and it goes into an endless “running” status and the logs say “insufficient rights to create a log file”, test script, code was taken from different projects for testing performance
Dag: test.py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator

from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta


default_args = {
         'owner': "Dan",
         'retries': 5,
         'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes = 2),
# 'run_as_user': 'root'
}

dag = DAG(
         dag_id = "first_dag",
         default_args = default_args,
         description = 'This is my first dag',
         start_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(minutes=1),
         schedule_interval='* * * * *',
         catchup=False)



task1 = BashOperator(task_id = 'first_task',
                     bash_command = "cd / && cd /opt/airflow/airflow_scripts && python3 test.py",
                 dag = dag
)

Python script test.py
#from selenium import webdriver
#from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

with open("lfasogs.txt", "a", encoding="UTF-8") as f:
         f.write(f"test\n")

Log screen:
enter image description here
Also, if I tried to run the script through the environment via bashoperator: "cd / && . /opt/airflow/virtualenvs/ym_trafficsource_connectors-ds-kcMFR/bin/activate && cd /opt/airflow/airflow_scripts/ && python3 test.py"
For some reason he cannot enter the environment and writes that he cannot import libraries

Tried to run dag as root, it gave an error launching dag
Tried to give root rights to all users in all containers, but the situation did not change
I tried to give write permission to the folder, but the situation did not change

